# how to change C-mode syntax so that the token @' is ignored?

Tags: syntax-table, c-mode

I edit some files that are mostly C code but include a few special extension tokens.  The tokens that give c-mode a problem are `@'` and `@"`.

I essentially want c-mode to ignore these two bigrams.  The current behavior is that the quote (single or double) is interpreted as the beginning of a quoted string.

I reckon this is childs play for anyone well versed in elisp syntax tables but I am not hence my appeal for your help.

Comment: I don't really care how @' and @" are colorized by font-lock, as long as they do not make c-mode think the quote is the beginning of a string

Comment: Also, perhaps this is more of a font-lock issue than a c-mode issue.  I'm not sure.

Comment: Is `@` used anywhere else? I wonder if `@` set to be “escape” in the syntax table would work: `(modify-syntax-entry ?@ "/")`

Comment: no, @ is not used anywhere else.  I'll investigate this option

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a `syntax-table` property on the `'` and `"` characters, e.g.:

```
(defun c-propertize-@ ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "@\\(\"\\|'\\)" nil t)
      (put-text-property (match-beginning 1)
                         (match-end 1)
                         'syntax-table
                         '(1))))) ;;= punctuation
```

Take a look at `syntax-propertize-function`, if you also want to edit these tokens.